# Magento 2 : After Migration from 1.9 to 2.2.2 data not show in Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, migration, data-migration

After migration from 1.9 to 2.2.2 data not show in admin panel 
ordered item position.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I consider you know how to use data-migration-tool.(**install & config**).

**Following:** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-migrate-data.html

just you need to help in map tables.so data can show in admin panel.

> To map magento 1.x tables in database (source)  `<source></source>` tag is  used.
>
> To map magento 2.x tables in database (destination)  `<destination></destination>`  tag is used.
>
> To map tables `<document_rules></document_rules>` tag is used.
>
> To map columns  `</field_rules></field_rules>`  is used.

check  `map.xml` file for :

1. you have to decide which table you need to ignore or not **e.g:**

   > For sales order grid data in admin panel comment or remove this.
   >
   > you may need to ignore extensions tables & columns  which exist in magento1.x database.

   `<source>
   <document_rules>
   <!-- <ignore>
                   <document>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid</document>
   </ignore>
   <ignore>
                   <document>sales_flat_invoice_grid</document>
   </ignore>
   <ignore>
                   <document>sales_flat_order_grid</document>
   </ignore>
   <ignore>
                   <document>sales_flat_shipment_grid</document>
   /ignore> -->

   </document_rules>
   </source>`
2. You have to exclude extra  columns which was created by extensions in Magento1.x but not in Magento 2 .
   **e.g:** `sales_flat_invoice_item.shipment_id` may be any **table.attribute_name**.

   `<source> 
       </field_rules>
       <ignore>
                   <field>sales_flat_invoice_item.shipment_id</field>
        </ignore>
       </field_rules>
   </source>`
3. You have to rename some table names. e.g

> All table changes & data structure can be  find [here](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento2/infographic-magento-1-vs-magento-2-database-structure/)

`<document_rules>
 <rename>
                <document>sales_flat_creditmemo_item</document>
                <to>sales_creditmemo_item</to>
    </rename>
 <rename>
                <document>sales_flat_invoice_item</document>
                <to>sales_invoice_item</to>
  </rename>
 <rename>
                <document>sales_flat_order_item</document>
                <to>sales_order_item</to>
 </rename>
 <rename>
                <document>sales_flat_quote_address_item</document>
                <to>quote_address_item</to>
            </rename>
  <rename>
                <document>sales_flat_quote_item</document>
                <to>quote_item</to>
 </rename>
 <rename>
                <document>sales_flat_quote_item_option</document>
                <to>quote_item_option</to>
  </rename>
 <rename>
                <document>sales_flat_shipment_item</document>
                <to>sales_shipment_item</to>
 </rename>
</document_rules>`

4. Most important just follow **errors** & **migration.log** file to solve.**e.g**

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry '1-17' for key
>   'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'